How to Handle 404 Errors and Skip to Next Track
I'm using just_audio with audio_service in my Flutter app for audio playback. The issue I’m encountering is when a media item URL returns a 404 error, the player goes into the idle state instead of skipping to the next track automatically.
Here’s the error I’m seeing in the logs:
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(16375): Playback error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(16375):   com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error
    E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(16375):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleIoException(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:644)
    E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(16375):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:616)
    E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(16375):       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(16375):       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
    E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(16375):       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
    E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(16375):       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
    E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(16375):   Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$InvalidResponseCodeException: Response code: 404
    E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(16375):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.open(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:413)
    E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(16375):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSource.open(DefaultDataSource.java:263)
    E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(16375):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.StatsDataSource.open(StatsDataSource.java:84)
    E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(16375):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ProgressiveMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ProgressiveMediaPeriod.java:1005)
    E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(16375):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:412)
    E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(16375):       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(16375):       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(16375):       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
    E/AudioPlayer(16375): TYPE_SOURCE: Response code: 404
    I/ExoPlayerImpl(16375): Release b5aecbc [ExoPlayerLib/2.18.7] [d2s, SM-N975F, samsung, 31] [goog.exo.core, goog.exo.exoplayer, goog.exo.decoder, goog.exo.datasource, goog.exo.extractor]

What I’m trying to achieve:
I want the player to automatically skip to the next track when a 404 error or any other playback error occurs.
The player should not skip when the user performs regular actions like pausing or stopping the playback.
Here’s my current code:
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:audio_service/audio_service.dart';
import 'package:audio_session/audio_session.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dotenv/flutter_dotenv.dart';
import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

class QueueState {
  static const QueueState empty =
      QueueState([], 0, [], AudioServiceRepeatMode.none);

  final List<MediaItem> queue;
  final int? queueIndex;
  final List<int>? shuffleIndices;
  final AudioServiceRepeatMode repeatMode;

  const QueueState(
      this.queue, this.queueIndex, this.shuffleIndices, this.repeatMode);

  bool get hasPrevious =>
      repeatMode != AudioServiceRepeatMode.none || (queueIndex ?? 0) > 0;
  bool get hasNext =>
      repeatMode != AudioServiceRepeatMode.none ||
      (queueIndex ?? 0) + 1 < queue.length;

  List<int> get indices =>
      shuffleIndices ?? List.generate(queue.length, (i) => i);
}

Future<AudioPlayerHandler> initAudioService() async {
  return await AudioService.init(
    builder: () => AudioPlayerHandlerImpl(),
    config: const AudioServiceConfig(
      androidNotificationChannelId: 'org.thitsarparami.app.audio',
      androidNotificationChannelName: 'သစ္စာပါရမီ',
      notificationColor: Color(0xff1751af),
      androidNotificationIcon: 'mipmap/ic_launcher',
      androidNotificationOngoing: true,
      //androidStopForegroundOnPause: true,
    ),
  );
}

/// An [AudioHandler] for playing a list of podcast episodes.
///
/// This class exposes the interface and not the implementation.
abstract class AudioPlayerHandler implements AudioHandler {
  Stream<QueueState> get queueState;
  Future<void> moveQueueItem(int currentIndex, int newIndex);
  ValueStream<double> get volume;
  Future<void> setVolume(double volume);
  ValueStream<double> get speed;
}

/// The implementation of [AudioPlayerHandler].
///
/// This handler is backed by a just_audio player. The player's effective
/// sequence is mapped onto the handler's queue, and the player's state is
/// mapped onto the handler's state.
class AudioPlayerHandlerImpl extends BaseAudioHandler
    with SeekHandler
    implements AudioPlayerHandler {
  // ignore: close_sinks
  final BehaviorSubject<List<MediaItem>> _recentSubject =
      BehaviorSubject.seeded(<MediaItem>[]);
  final _mediaLibrary = MediaLibrary();
  final _player = AudioPlayer();
  final _playlist = ConcatenatingAudioSource(children: []);
  @override
  final BehaviorSubject<double> volume = BehaviorSubject.seeded(1.0);
  @override
  final BehaviorSubject<double> speed = BehaviorSubject.seeded(1.0);
  final _mediaItemExpando = Expando<MediaItem>();

  /// A stream of the current effective sequence from just_audio.
  Stream<List<IndexedAudioSource>> get _effectiveSequence => Rx.combineLatest3<
              List<IndexedAudioSource>?,
              List<int>?,
              bool,
              List<IndexedAudioSource>?>(_player.sequenceStream,
          _player.shuffleIndicesStream, _player.shuffleModeEnabledStream,
          (sequence, shuffleIndices, shuffleModeEnabled) {
        if (sequence == null) return [];
        if (!shuffleModeEnabled) return sequence;
        if (shuffleIndices == null) return null;
        if (shuffleIndices.length != sequence.length) return null;
        return shuffleIndices.map((i) => sequence[i]).toList();
      }).whereType<List<IndexedAudioSource>>();

  /// Computes the effective queue index taking shuffle mode into account.
  int? getQueueIndex(
      int? currentIndex, bool shuffleModeEnabled, List<int>? shuffleIndices) {
    final effectiveIndices = _player.effectiveIndices ?? [];
    final shuffleIndicesInv = List.filled(effectiveIndices.length, 0);
    for (var i = 0; i < effectiveIndices.length; i++) {
      shuffleIndicesInv[effectiveIndices[i]] = i;
    }
    return (shuffleModeEnabled &&
            ((currentIndex ?? 0) < shuffleIndicesInv.length))
        ? shuffleIndicesInv[currentIndex ?? 0]
        : currentIndex;
  }

  /// A stream reporting the combined state of the current queue and the current
  /// media item within that queue.
  @override
  Stream<QueueState> get queueState =>
      Rx.combineLatest3<List<MediaItem>, PlaybackState, List<int>, QueueState>(
          queue,
          playbackState,
          _player.shuffleIndicesStream.whereType<List<int>>(),
          (queue, playbackState, shuffleIndices) => QueueState(
                queue,
                playbackState.queueIndex,
                playbackState.shuffleMode == AudioServiceShuffleMode.all
                    ? shuffleIndices
                    : null,
                playbackState.repeatMode,
              )).where((state) =>
          state.shuffleIndices == null ||
          state.queue.length == state.shuffleIndices!.length);

  @override
  Future<void> setShuffleMode(AudioServiceShuffleMode shuffleMode) async {
    final enabled = shuffleMode == AudioServiceShuffleMode.all;
    if (enabled) {
      await _player.shuffle();
    }
    playbackState.add(playbackState.value.copyWith(shuffleMode: shuffleMode));
    await _player.setShuffleModeEnabled(enabled);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> setRepeatMode(AudioServiceRepeatMode repeatMode) async {
    playbackState.add(playbackState.value.copyWith(repeatMode: repeatMode));
    await _player.setLoopMode(LoopMode.values[repeatMode.index]);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> setSpeed(double speed) async {
    this.speed.add(speed);
    await _player.setSpeed(speed);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> setVolume(double volume) async {
    this.volume.add(volume);
    await _player.setVolume(volume);
  }

  AudioPlayerHandlerImpl() {
    _init();
  }

  Future<void> _init() async {
    final session = await AudioSession.instance;
    await session.configure(const AudioSessionConfiguration.speech());
    // Broadcast speed changes. Debounce so that we don't flood the notification
    // with updates.
    speed.debounceTime(const Duration(milliseconds: 250)).listen((speed) {
      playbackState.add(playbackState.value.copyWith(speed: speed));
    });
    // Load and broadcast the initial queue
    // await updateQueue(_mediaLibrary.items[MediaLibrary.albumsRootId]);

    // For Android 11, record the most recent item so it can be resumed.
    mediaItem
        .whereType<MediaItem>()
        .listen((item) => _recentSubject.add([item]));
// Broadcast media item changes.
    Rx.combineLatest4<int?, List<MediaItem>, bool, List<int>?, MediaItem?>(
        _player.currentIndexStream,
        queue,
        _player.shuffleModeEnabledStream,
        _player.shuffleIndicesStream,
        (index, queue, shuffleModeEnabled, shuffleIndices) {
      final queueIndex =
          getQueueIndex(index, shuffleModeEnabled, shuffleIndices);
      return (queueIndex != null && queueIndex < queue.length)
          ? queue[queueIndex]
          : null;
    }).whereType<MediaItem>().distinct().listen(mediaItem.add);

    // Propagate all events from the audio player to AudioService clients.
    _player.playbackEventStream.listen(_broadcastState);
    _player.shuffleModeEnabledStream
        .listen((enabled) => _broadcastState(_player.playbackEvent));
    // In this example, the service stops when reaching the end.
    _player.processingStateStream.listen((state) {
      if (state == ProcessingState.completed) {
        stop();
        _player.seek(Duration.zero, index: 0);
      }
    });
    // In this example, the service stops when reaching the end.
    // Broadcast the current queue.
    _effectiveSequence
        .map((sequence) =>
            sequence.map((source) => _mediaItemExpando[source]!).toList())
        .pipe(queue);
    // Load the playlist.
    _playlist.addAll(queue.value.map(_itemToSource).toList());
    await _player.setAudioSource(_playlist, preload: false);
  }

  @override
  Future<List<MediaItem>> getChildren(String parentMediaId,
      [Map<String, dynamic>? options]) async {
    switch (parentMediaId) {
      case AudioService.recentRootId:
        // When the user resumes a media session, tell the system what the most
        // recently played item was.
        return _recentSubject.value;
      default:
        // Allow client to browse the media library.
        return _mediaLibrary.items[parentMediaId]!;
    }
  }

  @override
  ValueStream<Map<String, dynamic>> subscribeToChildren(String parentMediaId) {
    switch (parentMediaId) {
      case AudioService.recentRootId:
        final stream = _recentSubject.map((_) => <String, dynamic>{});
        return _recentSubject.hasValue
            ? stream.shareValueSeeded(<String, dynamic>{})
            : stream.shareValue();
      default:
        return Stream.value(_mediaLibrary.items[parentMediaId])
            .map((_) => <String, dynamic>{})
            .shareValue();
    }
  }

  UriAudioSource _itemToSource(MediaItem mediaItem) {
    final String radioUrl = dotenv.env['RADIO_URL']!;
    final uri = mediaItem.extras == null
        ? Uri.parse(radioUrl)
        : Uri.parse(mediaItem.extras?['url']);

    final audioSource = AudioSource.uri(uri, tag: mediaItem);
    _mediaItemExpando[audioSource] = mediaItem;
    return audioSource;
  }

  List<AudioSource> _itemsToSources(List<MediaItem> mediaItems) =>
      mediaItems.map(_itemToSource).toList();

  @override
  Future<void> addQueueItem(MediaItem mediaItem) async {
    await _playlist.add(_itemToSource(mediaItem));
  }

  @override
  Future<void> addQueueItems(List<MediaItem> mediaItems) async {
    await _playlist.addAll(_itemsToSources(mediaItems));
  }

  @override
  Future<void> insertQueueItem(int index, MediaItem mediaItem) async {
    await _playlist.insert(index, _itemToSource(mediaItem));
  }

  @override
  Future<void> updateQueue(List<MediaItem> queue) async {
    await _playlist.clear();
    await _playlist.addAll(_itemsToSources(queue));
  }

  @override
  // ignore: avoid_renaming_method_parameters
  Future<void> updateMediaItem(MediaItem newMediaItem) async {
    // rewrite updateMediaItem function because it is need to notify the mediaItem about favourite or unfavourite.
    final index = queue.value.indexWhere((item) => item.id == newMediaItem.id);
    if (index != -1) {
      queue.value[index] = newMediaItem;
      _playlist.children[index] = _itemToSource(newMediaItem);
      _player.sequenceState!.sequence[index] = _itemToSource(newMediaItem);
      _mediaItemExpando[_player.sequence![index]] = newMediaItem;
      mediaItem.add(newMediaItem);
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<void> removeQueueItem(MediaItem mediaItem) async {
    final index = queue.value.indexOf(mediaItem);
    await _playlist.removeAt(index);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> removeQueueItemAt(int index) async {
    await _playlist.removeAt(index);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> moveQueueItem(int currentIndex, int newIndex) async {
    await _playlist.move(currentIndex, newIndex);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> skipToNext() => _player.seekToNext();

  @override
  Future<void> skipToPrevious() => _player.seekToPrevious();

  @override
  Future<void> skipToQueueItem(int index) async {
    if (index < 0 || index >= _playlist.children.length) return;
    // This jumps to the beginning of the queue item at [index].
    _player.seek(Duration.zero,
        index: _player.shuffleModeEnabled
            ? _player.shuffleIndices![index]
            : index);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> play() => _player.play();

  @override
  Future<void> pause() => _player.pause();

  @override
  Future<void> seek(Duration position) async {
    await _player.seek(position);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> stop() async {
    await _player.stop();
    await playbackState.firstWhere(
        (state) => state.processingState == AudioProcessingState.idle);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> fastForward() async {
    _player.seek(Duration(seconds: _player.position.inSeconds + 15));
  }

  @override
  Future<void> rewind() async {
    _player.seek(Duration(seconds: _player.position.inSeconds - 15));
  }

  /// Broadcasts the current state to all clients.
  void _broadcastState(PlaybackEvent event) {
    final playing = _player.playing;
    final queueIndex = getQueueIndex(
        event.currentIndex, _player.shuffleModeEnabled, _player.shuffleIndices);
    playbackState.add(playbackState.value.copyWith(
      controls: [
        MediaControl.skipToPrevious,
        if (playing) MediaControl.pause else MediaControl.play,
        MediaControl.stop,
        MediaControl.skipToNext,
      ],
      systemActions: const {
        MediaAction.seek,
        MediaAction.seekForward,
        MediaAction.seekBackward,
      },
      androidCompactActionIndices: const [0, 1, 3],
      processingState: const {
        ProcessingState.idle: AudioProcessingState.idle,
        ProcessingState.loading: AudioProcessingState.loading,
        ProcessingState.buffering: AudioProcessingState.buffering,
        ProcessingState.ready: AudioProcessingState.ready,
        ProcessingState.completed: AudioProcessingState.completed,
      }[_player.processingState]!,
      playing: playing,
      updatePosition: _player.position,
      bufferedPosition: _player.bufferedPosition,
      speed: _player.speed,
      queueIndex: queueIndex,
    ));
  }
}

// Provides access to a library of media items. In your app, this could come
// from a database or web service.
class MediaLibrary {
  static const albumsRootId = 'albums';
  static final String radioUrl = dotenv.env['RADIO_URL'] ?? 'default_radio_url';
  final items = <String, List<MediaItem>>{
  };
}

